# React native not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, react-native

I am following this [guide](http://www.proreactnative.com/Getting-Started-with-React-Native-on-Ubuntu-Linux/) to get react native working on ubuntu.But 'react-native start' command keeps showing 'react-native: command not found'.What could be the possible cause for this?

Comment: Are you sure you installed react-native correctly `(sudo) npm install -g react-native-cli` ? You can see all your **globally** installed packages typing `npm ls -g` so `npm ls -g | grep react-native-cli` should output something like *react-native-cli@0.1.X*.

Comment: Yes. I get '+-- react-native-cli@0.1.10' as output.